# CSS nth-child: How will nth-child will work even inside a container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.zebra:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>

<div>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
</div>

<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>

<div>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
</div>

<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a series of paragraph above with `zebra` class but nth-child Resets when Wrap inside a container. Is it possible that it does not resets even inside a container?

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

[image: Result of above code]

**EXPECTED RESULT**

[image: Expected Result]

w3schools link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPLP7CUMGSPD

Comment: no it's not possible ... that's clear

Comment: @TemaniAfif is there any work around for this scenario?

Comment: the first easy work around is jQuery ... with CSS it may be a bit complex and lead to lot of code

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: If both the numbers of paragraphs outside and inside containers is unknown, no not possible. If it's always odd (x)or even inside container, a selector with huge number of commas may do the job. If not, a paragraph after a container has no way of knowing if it was odd or even in that container… Count in server-side language or in the browser with a script and add class where relevant :)

Comment: You can kind of hardcode it, but you would need a lot of code for each new block, where paragraphs are inside something: https://jsfiddle.net/z60sm1k6/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this would not be possible by simply using the `:nth-child` pseudo class.

You can use JQuery however to get all of the odd instances of your class on the page and add a class to them. With this class, you can then style as appropriate.

An example:

```js
$('.zebra:odd').addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>

<div>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
</div>

<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>

<div>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
  <p class="zebra">Paragraph Inside</p>
</div>

<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>
<p class="zebra">Paragraph</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.